# Bitcoin LND Lightning Network Daemon, pending open channel, opening transaction never confirmed

Tags: lightning-network-daemon, ln-opening-channels

I'm running LND 0.7.0-beta on top of Bitcoind 0.18.0 and have a channel that has been pending on opening for more than a month now.
It tried to open when I was still running LND 0.6.1-beta.

The txid in the channel_point can't be found through blockexplorers so I must conclude the transaction never got included in a block.

Is there a way to make LND realize this channel does not exist and give me back control of the balance?

I tried using closechannel but that did not work, because the channel is not open.
Here are the relevant log entries and output from pendingchannels and closechannel.
The channel I'm concerned with is the first one in pending channels, the second one is stuck too though.

```
2019-07-04 21:44:07.716 [WRN] FNDG: ChainNotifier shutting down, cannot complete funding flow for ChannelPoint(4cd80ac2bb753ae11f4de9c5eb273732480fb9d09b7599009b62d26f5199753b:1)
2019-07-04 21:44:56.217 [INF] NTFN: New spend subscription: spend_id=25, outpoint=4cd80ac2bb753ae11f4de9c5eb273732480fb9d09b7599009b62d26f5199753b:1, height_hint=583848           
2019-07-04 21:44:56.272 [INF] CNCT: Close observer for ChannelPoint(4cd80ac2bb753ae11f4de9c5eb273732480fb9d09b7599009b62d26f5199753b:1) active                                     
2019-07-04 21:44:56.715 [INF] CNCT: ChannelArbitrator(4cd80ac2bb753ae11f4de9c5eb273732480fb9d09b7599009b62d26f5199753b:1): starting state=StateDefault                             
2019-07-04 21:44:57.280 [INF] LNWL: Inserting unconfirmed transaction 4cd80ac2bb753ae11f4de9c5eb273732480fb9d09b7599009b62d26f5199753b                                             
2019-07-04 21:44:57.290 [ERR] FNDG: Unable to rebroadcast funding tx for ChannelPoint(4cd80ac2bb753ae11f4de9c5eb273732480fb9d09b7599009b62d26f5199753b:1): Transaction rejected: output already spent
2019-07-04 21:44:57.291 [INF] NTFN: New confirmation subscription: txid=4cd80ac2bb753ae11f4de9c5eb273732480fb9d09b7599009b62d26f5199753b, num_confs=3                              
2019-07-04 21:44:57.291 [INF] NTFN: New confirmation subscription: conf_id=2, txid=4cd80ac2bb753ae11f4de9c5eb273732480fb9d09b7599009b62d26f5199753b, height_hint=583848            
2019-07-04 21:44:57.291 [INF] FNDG: Waiting for funding tx (4cd80ac2bb753ae11f4de9c5eb273732480fb9d09b7599009b62d26f5199753b) to reach 3 confirmations                             
2019-07-04 21:44:58.101 [WRN] PEER: Unable to find our forwarding policy for channel 4cd80ac2bb753ae11f4de9c5eb273732480fb9d09b7599009b62d26f5199753b:1, using default values      
2019-07-04 21:44:58.102 [INF] HSWC: ChannelLink(4cd80ac2bb753ae11f4de9c5eb273732480fb9d09b7599009b62d26f5199753b:1) is starting                                                    
2019-07-04 21:44:58.103 [INF] HSWC: HTLC manager for ChannelPoint(4cd80ac2bb753ae11f4de9c5eb273732480fb9d09b7599009b62d26f5199753b:1) started, bandwidth=879768000 mSAT            
2019-07-04 21:44:58.103 [INF] HSWC: Attempting to re-resynchronize ChannelPoint(4cd80ac2bb753ae11f4de9c5eb273732480fb9d09b7599009b62d26f5199753b:1)                                
2019-07-04 21:45:28.104 [INF] HSWC: ChannelLink(4cd80ac2bb753ae11f4de9c5eb273732480fb9d09b7599009b62d26f5199753b:1) has exited                                                     
2019-07-04 21:45:28.104 [INF] HSWC: ChannelLink(4cd80ac2bb753ae11f4de9c5eb273732480fb9d09b7599009b62d26f5199753b:1) is stopping                                                    

$ lncli pendingchannels
{
    "total_limbo_balance": "0",
    "pending_open_channels": [
        {
            "channel": {
                "remote_node_pub": "020f49831fd13556e5b03239df888ca031edaebe5b4efccd52d2f5c6742a743ad6",
                "channel_point": "4cd80ac2bb753ae11f4de9c5eb273732480fb9d09b7599009b62d26f5199753b:1",
                "capacity": "900000",
                "local_balance": "888768",
                "remote_balance": "0"
            },
            "confirmation_height": 0,
            "commit_fee": "11232",
            "commit_weight": "600",
            "fee_per_kw": "15515"
        }
    ],
    "pending_closing_channels": [
    ],
    "pending_force_closing_channels": [
        {
            "channel": {
                "remote_node_pub": "025a625a9aa3d7c2f9a7eaa6bdb2278200b2871d35d51ab1e5bc8979078e9e1036",
                "channel_point": "5e5c88386aaa1f57b293530f175fa76b28d17fc39cc8ee2eb075ec370a2160b2:1",
                "capacity": "285083",
                "local_balance": "2000",
                "remote_balance": "0"
            },
            "closing_txid": "1f90bf8f7065c3e90fbf72b3268ed57554c5f407e3a13397743e45048e3be546",
            "limbo_balance": "0",
            "maturity_height": 0,
            "blocks_til_maturity": 0,
            "recovered_balance": "0",
            "pending_htlcs": [
            ]
        }
    ],
    "waiting_close_channels": [
    ]
}

$ lncli closechannel 4cd80ac2bb753ae11f4de9c5eb273732480fb9d09b7599009b62d26f5199753b
[lncli] rpc error: code = Unknown desc = channel not found
```

Comment: Does the channel show up when you call `lncli listchannels` or `lncli pendingchannels`? Do you have the txid? Perhaps the `abandonchannel` command could be helpful, but I think it may only work for opened channels, not pending (?)

Comment: The channel does not show up from listchannels, it does show in pendingchannels, the output I posted above is from pendingchannels.
The channel_point is 4cd80ac2bb753ae11f4de9c5eb273732480fb9d09b7599009b62d26f5199753b:1
Txid should be 4cd80ac2bb753ae11f4de9c5eb273732480fb9d09b7599009b62d26f5199753b which can't be found in block explorers.
I think the channel never opened, but LND does not realize.

If I use abandon channel would that add the channel balance back to the normal on-chain balance?